# Pipe of Insight mechanics

Tags: dota-2

Pipe of Insights is an item that grant to the owner a passive magic resistance of 30% and if activated it creates a shield that blocks 400 spell damage.

[image: Pipe of Insight]

When the hero that carry the Pipe of Insights activates it, and is then targeted by an enemy skill, like for example Lion's Finger of Death, is the 30% magic resistance calculated first, or instead is the shield 400 damage block that intervene first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shield blocks 400 damage regardless of magic resistance.

The 30% Magic Resistance is calculated everytime,as it is passive.

So, for the Fingers of Death Example :

If you dont have the shield activated, it will deal -30% damage.
If you do, it will still dealing -30% damage, and the rest of the damage will be used to 
lower your "shield" ammount of Magic Block.

Lion's ultimate info can be found [here](http://www.playdota.com/heroes/demon-witch)

```
Level 1 : 500 Damage - 600  With Aghanim's
Level 2 : 650 Damage - 800  With Aghanim's
Level 3 : 850 Damage - 1025 With Aghanim's
```

So, 30% Magic Res. would lower the damages to:

```
Level 1 : 500 - 150 = 350 Damage Or 600  - 180   = 420   With Aghanim's
Level 2 : 650 - 195 = 455 Damage Or 800  - 240   = 560   With Aghanim's
Level 3 : 850 - 255 = 595 Damage Or 1025 - 307.5 = 717.5 With Aghanim's
```

So, ignoring any extra Magic Defense that the heroe may have, you would be able to completely ignore the ultimate's damage only if he is at Level 1, and without Aghanims.

Otherwise, you would take some extra damage.

Hope it Helps.

Source : Self tested @ Dota 2 with Friends.

Comment: oh, niiice, the shield effect is more useful than I thought

Comment: Another way to look at it is that the shield effectively blocks ~571 magic damage, after you factor in the reduction from the item itself. If you have other sources of damage reduction then it becomes even more effective, as the flat number is magnified by the percentage decrease.

Comment: Yes.As i've said, i am not taking consideration any other source of Magic Defense that the Heroe might have

Comment: Just kidding, we were wrong. The Pipe's shield blocks a static 400 damage regardless of magic resistance.